# Windows Batch Nested For options was unexpected error

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to write a batch file with nested for loops. The purpose is to read lines which can have empty tokens and extract email addresses which is one of the tokens. 
example data from the file I am trying to read

```
|4|HistoryDates|History Dates Check|Check history data store tables for valid dss_start and dss_end_date combinations|DataStore|History|01 Source System||||||dss_eff_start_date > dss_eff_end_date or (dss_current_ind = 'Y' and dss_eff_end_date <> to_date('2999-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd'))||N||||Y|Email|lijo.samuel
```

The code I have written

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
setlocal enableextensions
for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%G in (%LOAD_FILE%) do (
SET LINE="%%G"
SET "LINE="!LINE:^|="|"!""
REM echo !LINE!
for /F "usebackq delim=| tokens=2,5" %%H in ("!LINE!") do echo email %%~H
```

The first loop runs fine but the 2nd loop errors out saying

[image]

Comment: you didn't close the first for loop

Comment: This utility will helps with that as well. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5702

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is about the typo "delim=". Should be "delims=" as a colleague pointed out. The delimiter '|' works without escaping. Thanks for the responses though.